# For two arbitrary events A and B, prove that Pr(A) = Pr(A ∩ B) + Pr(A ∩ $B^c$).

Tags: probability

For two arbitrary events A and B, prove that
$$\Pr(A) = \Pr(A ∩ B) + \Pr(A ∩ B^\complement)$$

So I know the theorem that $$A = (A ∩ B) ∪ (A ∩ B^\complement) $$

I suppose I have to derive the formula using it.

Comment: You need to know more than the theorem you state to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A\cap B$ and $A\cap B^c$ are disjoint. What can you say about the probability of a union of two disjoint events?

Comment: That's correct. Of course the disjointness is crucial.